# How to move spans with an animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap framework and I have two span4 centered using offset class.
What I'm trying to do is doing an animation removing the offset class and pulling the spans to the right to put another span4 at the end.

I mean, doing what I do in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/8/) (to see the result is better enter [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/8/embedded/result/)) with a slide animation of the two first spans to the right and a fadeIn/fadeOut annimation with the third span.

**CSS**

```
.span4 {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="rowad" class="row-fluid">
        <div id="firstspan" class="span4 offset2">Hello
            <button class="btn" id="addspan">Add SPAN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">Stack</div>
        <div id="spanhiden"class="span4 hidden">Stack</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addspan").click(function () {
       var textb = $(this).text();

       if (textb == "Add SPAN"){
           $("#firstspan").removeClass("offset2");
           $("#spanhiden").removeClass("hidden");
           $(this).text("Remove SPAN");
       }else{
           $("#firstspan").addClass("offset2");
           $("#spanhiden").addClass("hidden");
           $(this).text("Add SPAN");
       }
    });
});
```

---

Any advice or help would be appreciated. Iff you need more info, let me know and i'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you use CSS3?  If so , use CSS transitions.  Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
.span4 {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/10/

Comment: Hey! thanks! good solution! But how i can do to fadein/fadeout the third span when the slide animation is finished? I'm afraid right now it appears too sharply...

Comment: It is little bit tricky. But in your case you can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/11/

Comment: Really thanks! Last thing: I'm trying to use fadeIn() function instead of show(), but does not works... do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/21/embedded/result/

Comment: It may be a conflict ion with css animations. try this http://jsfiddle.net/V6qGM/22/ but you have to handle the alignment

Comment: Oh... for things like this I don't like to put _all_ in the CSS animations. Do you know what is the specific property that I have to put? :)

Comment: For first on it is `margin` and second one `opacity`